# AES-NI on macOS assembly bad acces

Tags: macos, assembly, encryption, aes, inline-assembly

I am trying to implement AES-NI on macOS 10.12 Sierra. Here is the code I use to check AES-NI support:

```
 .section __TEXT,__text
 .globl _main
 _main:
     mov %eax, 1;
     CPUID;
     test %ecx,0x2000000;
```

And here are the commands I use to compile it:

```
as aes.asm -o aes.o
ld asm.o -e _main -o aes
```

And it always fails with `EXC_BAD_ACCESS (code=1, address=0x1)`. I tried running it with lldb and it points line `mov %eax, 1`. I also tried to use this piece of code from C asm inline. And the result is the same. I also tried running this code on Windows machine (as an asm inline, compiled in Clion with Cygwin) and it worked. Am I missing something? Does the process of checking AES-NI support differ for macOS?

Comment: You seem to be using at&t syntax. The correct code would be `movl $1, %eax; cpuid; testl $0x2000000, %eax`. Maybe switch to intel if you are confused by at&t. Also, you will obviously need to exit your program otherwise you will just delay the fault :)

Comment: This should have resulted in a syntax error when run through `as`, not a runtime error. You never should have gotten that far.

Comment: @CodyGray why? That is all valid syntax, `mov %eax, 1` will just try to move `eax` into memory address `1` and that will fault at runtime.

Comment: @Jester you're right. It works now, thanks.

Comment: I get an error that the mnemonic doesn't have a size suffix.

Comment: @CodyGray do you put '%' before register name (e.g. %eax)?

Comment: Yes, I copied the code as written here. I know how to write it *correctly*. I'm just saying, it's weird to me that your assembler accepted that.